# FFMPEG android very slow converting raw aac to mp3

Tags: android, performance, audio, ffmpeg

I managed to compile ffmpeg for android from this repo:
https://github.com/aksalj/ffmpeg-android
So you can see the configuration options in here:
https://github.com/aksalj/ffmpeg-android/blob/master/config.sh

The only changes I did were to change the darwin-x86_54 to darwin-x86 since the new r9b NDK only comes with it and also change the androideabi-4.4.3 to androideabi-4.6 again because of the new NDK. I am encoding a raw ADTS aac to mp3, the decoder for aac is libav and encoder for mp3 is libmp3lame. Even though the process works a simple 5 minute aac files (44100, 2ch) is taking about 3 minutes to process. The same file on my mac (with the macports ffmpeg) takes a few seconds.

I am not sure but are there any optimizations that can be made to the ffmpeg config script or maybe i need to compile ffmpeg with something like libaacplus(even though i think aacplus is used for encoding only, so shouldnt make a difference).Anyways any performance optimizations will be highly appreciated!

The android device is a US Galaxy S3 (i747m model which has the Snapdragon S4).

Comment: Yes, libaacplus is an encoder for HE-AAC and ffmpeg can natively decode most AAC streams. Perhaps [libshine](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libshine-fxp/) will perform better than libmp3lame for your platform. You would need to compile ffmpeg with `--enable-libshine`.

Comment: https://vec.io/posts/use-android-hardware-decoder-with-omxcodec-in-ndk  covers hardware acceleration via android 'stagefright' lib. On a low power device, its gonna be slow unless you are using hardware. AFAIK - ffmpeg is still software only.

Comment: Actually it turns out part of the issue was that i was compiling against a arm v5, when my device was arm v7 so it couldn't make use of all the optimizations. I made some changes and it is way faster now. I have to test it a bit more before answering this question. @LordNeckbeard libshine sounds like it's going to be a lot faster but it is pain to compile and i havent been able to so far (no doc whatsover too)